# Mathematica "export" function creates irritating pop-up window when generating graphics

Tags: graphics, popup, window, wolfram-mathematica, export

Is there a way to prevent Mathematica(7)'s Export function from creating annoying pop-up windows when it is used to created graphics? I understand that it has to call the front end and use the system's window manager to create the graphics, but when I am running automated generation of a lot of graphics in the background it is extremely disruptive to have these blank windows popping up and disappearing constantly. It occurs when using Mathematica through the front-end and through the kernel for batch jobs.

I can find no discussion on this anywhere, surely I am not the only one who finds this really annoying. My OS is Ubuntu 9.10, perhaps this doesn't happen on other OS's?

Comment: I don't get that on MacOS with the same version.  So, post your code and we'll see if it is any different than what I (or, others) do.

Comment: Perhaps you need to tell it what filename you want. Check out the documentation for the syntax of the `Export` function.

Comment: Just to add another point, I get no popups running mma from the frontend or the command line, either on OS X 10.7 or opensuse. So supplying code would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 and I couldn't get any popup windows when generating graphics in Mathematica 7 or 8.

For example, create a file "makegraphs.m" containing the following

```
num = 10;

g = Graphics[];
Do[g = Show[g, Plot[Sin[i x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[2][i]]];
     (*Print[g];*)
     Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "g"<>ToString[i]<>".eps"}], g], 
   {i, 1, num}];
Exit[]
```

which you call from the shell using `math -noprompt -initfile "makegraphs.m"` or `math -noprompt -run "<<makegraphs.m"`,
for command-line switches, see the version 7 documentation: [math](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/program/math.html).
This does **not** create any frontend windows even when the print statement is uncommented.

Note that graphics <s>never</s> do not normally display when using the Mathematica command prompt: e.g.

```
:~$ math7
Mathematica 7.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2009 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= Plot[x,{x,0,1}]

Out[1]= -Graphics-
```

However, if you are (automatically) loading a package like `` <<JavaGraphics` ``, then the command prompt will produce graphics windows - but they won't be blank, nor Mathematica notebook windows.

Maybe you can post some of the code you're using?

Also, have you tried `SetOptions[Plot,DisplayFunction->Identity]`?

---

Note that in Mathematica version 8, a [script mode](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaScripts.html) has been added (see also [math](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/math.html)).

Comment: Aha, thank you, indeed SetOptions[Plot,DisplayFunction->Identity] seems to fix this. Your code produces the pop-up windows on my system; I have no idea why I am seeing this but not you guys, but thanks for helping me get rid of it nonetheless :).